# Multiple viewports in 2.8 object mode?

Tags: versions

In the old blender, as well as most other 3d programs, you can display multiple viewports each with their own orientation, top, right, left, back and front,

I don't see any way to do this in 2.8 object mode. Is it possible?

Comment: One way is to enable Quad View.    From the 3D Editor : View menu > Area > Toggle Quad View.     Key board short toggle =  Ctrl Alt Q

Comment: @3fingeredfrog please add the answer in answer section.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to enable Quad View.

From the 3D Editor: **View menu** > **Area** > **Toggle Quad View**.

Key board short toggle = **Ctrl** **Alt** **Q**

[image]